# How to print Dynamic nested Json arrays in a Tree Structure by matching the parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how to print this dynamic Json array in a tree format 
the output i expect is like this

```
firstname :- test
Last name :-test1

Account=>

          role :-test3

          status:test4

Account1=>

   role:-

   status:-
```

json

```
 $scope.inputs = [
    {
      "firstname" : "Test"
    },{
      "lastname" : "Test1"
    },{                           
      "Account" : [

        {"role" : "Test3"},
        {"status" : "Test4"},
      ]
    },
    {
      "Account1" : [

        {"role" : "Test3"},
        {"status" : "Test4"},
      ]
    },
    {
      "Account2" : [

        {"role" : {
          'dim3': {
            'dim4':{
              'dim5':'cccc'
            }
          }
        }

      },
        {"status" : "Test4"},
        {"status" : "Test4"},
      ]
    },
    {
    "ending" : "yes"
  }
  ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by including recursively in your template another template that  render differently each value in your object depending on it's still an object or not.
The function isArrayOrObject is used to check if a value is an object or not

```
//index.html:

<body ng-app="mainApp">
    <div ng-controller="controller">    
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in inputs" ng-include="'node_renderer.html'"></li>
        </ul>       
    </div>
</body>

//node_renderer.html: a template to be included that render each value in the object:

<div ng-switch="isArrayOrObject(value)">
    <div ng-switch-when="false">{{key}}: {{value}}</div>
    <div ng-switch-when="true">
        <span>{{key}}=></span>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in value" ng-include="'node_renderer.html'"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


app.controller('controller', function($scope) {

    $scope.isArrayOrObject = function(value) {
        return angular.isObject(value);
    };      

    $scope.inputs = [
    {
      "firstname" : "Test"
    },{
      "lastname" : "Test1"
    },{                           
      "Account" : [

        {"role" : "Test3"},
        {"status" : "Test4"},
      ]
    },
    {
      "Account1" : [

        {"role" : "Test3"},
        {"status" : "Test4"},
      ]
    },
    {
      "Account2" : [

        {"role" : {
          'dim3': {
            'dim4':{
              'dim5':'cccc'
            }
          }
        }

      },
        {"status" : "Test4"},
        {"status" : "Test4"},
      ]
    },
    {
        "ending" : "yes"
    }
    ];  
});
```

Comment: :- what if in the case of dynamic json.if it can be modified at any time

Comment: :- what is node_renderer.html

Comment: it's the <div ng-switch="isArrayOrObject(value)"> ... put in a separate html file

Comment: I created a plunk, look at this:
https://plnkr.co/edit/EylQaVJlFGvJGS9HqhsK?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

you can assign the first key property and value of an each object to one object like this

```
$scope.inputs.forEach(function(data){
      obj[Object.keys(data)[0]] = data[Object.keys(data)[0]]
});
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
$scope.inputs = [
    {
      "firstname" : "Test"
    },{
      "lastname" : "Test1"
    },{                           
      "Account" : [

        {"role" : "Test3"},
        {"status" : "Test4"},
      ]
    },
    {
      "Account1" : [

        {"role" : "Test3"},
        {"status" : "Test4"},
      ]
    },
    {
      "Account2" : [

        {"role" : {
          'dim3': {
            'dim4':{
              'dim5':'cccc'
            }
          }
        }

      },
        {"status" : "Test4"},
        {"status" : "Test4"},
      ]
    },
    {
    "ending" : "yes"
  }
  ];
  var obj= {};
  $scope.inputs.forEach(function(data){
      obj[Object.keys(data)[0]] = data[Object.keys(data)[0]]
  });
  //var arr = $scope.inputs.map(o=> o);
    console.log(obj)
  

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 
</div>
```

Comment: :- i dont need my result as json i want my results in the format i have given,,it should print in that way

Comment: do you need to print it in the html

Comment: :- yes i need to print this in html with using a single ng-repeat if possible..can you help me with that