# How to display the output in Tree structure by matching the parent?

Tags: angularjs

How can I get the output in tree structure by matching the parent? I can only use a single `ng-repeat` to display this.

My expected output

```
firstname :-dsfsdf
lastname :- fdsfsdfs
account:
    role:-dsfsdf
    status:-dsfdfsfds
```

**js**

```
  var app = angular.module("test",[]);

    app.controller("MainCtrl",function($scope){

      $scope.inputs = [
        {
          "firstname" : "Test"
        },{
          "lastname" : "Test1"
        },{                           
          "Account" : [

            {"role" : "Test3"},
            {"status" : "Test4"},
          ]
        },
        {
          "Account1" : [

            {"role" : "Test3"},
            {"status" : "Test4"},
          ]
        },
        {
          "Account2" : [

            {"role" : {
              'dim3': {
                'dim4':{
                  'dim5':'cccc'
                }
              }
            }

          },
            {"status" : "Test4"},
            {"status" : "Test4"},
          ]
        },
        {
        "ending" : "yes"
      }
      ];
    /*$scope.person = [];*/



    $scope.myPersonObj = [];

        $scope.checkIndex1 = function(arg, myPersonObj)
        {
            if (angular.isArray(arg) || angular.isObject(arg)) {
                angular.forEach(arg, function (value, key) {
                    console.log(value + "started");
                    if(angular.isObject(value) || angular.isArray(value))
                    {
                        $scope.checkIndex1(value, myPersonObj);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log( value + "pushing--test");
                        myPersonObj.push(arg);
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                console.log( value + "pushing1");
                myPersonObj.push(arg);
            }      
        }

        $scope.checkIndex1($scope.inputs, $scope.myPersonObj);

        console.log("myPersonObj :"+ JSON.stringify($scope.myPersonObj));

        console.log($scope.inputs[2] + "del");
    }):
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print Dynamic nested Json arrays in a Tree Structure by matching the parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43337645/how-to-print-dynamic-nested-json-arrays-in-a-tree-structure-by-matching-the-pare)